# How to implement iter.collect::<Vec<Vec<_>>>()?

Tags: rust, iterator

[`Iterator::collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) can transform iterators into so many different structures. So, I was expecting that the [following](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=14ff92c9b560f4474bc91666e02b3dc1) would just work:

```rust
let it = (1..5).map(|x| (x..5));
let xss = it.collect::<Vec<Vec<_>>>();
// let xss = it.map(|xs| xs.collect::<Vec<_>>()).collect::<Vec<_>>(); // clunky
```

No luck, unfortunately. How can such functionality be implemented?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a two-step procedure. First, you should create an iterator of `Vec<_>`, then collect it.

```rust
let it = (1..5).map(|x| (x..5).collect());
let xss = it.collect::<Vec<Vec<_>>>();
```

See the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=67c460525a7e39bf933630a2d7161756).

---

Alternatively, if you can't modify right away the iterator:

```rust
let it = (1..5).map(|x| (x..5));
let xss = it.map(|x| x.collect()).collect::<Vec<Vec<_>>>();
```

Comment: Thank you. I meant how to implement `collect` so that it builds a nested vec in one call.

Comment: You can't, due to the [orphan rule](https://rust-lang.github.io/chalk/book/clauses/coherence.html), because to transform an interator into a type `T`, `T` has to implement `FromIterator`; and, in this case, it's `Vec` which implements `FromIterator`. Since both `Vec` and `FromIterator` are not defined in your crate (they are provided by the standard library), you can't modify their behavior.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thank you.